# A good RGB formulae in gnuplot for colored and gray 2d contour prints

Tags: gnuplot

I have a question about a handsome colorpalette for 2d contour plots in gnuplot. Based on the gnuplot manual and help function, I figured out that there are some pre-defined colors palettes like:

```
Some nice schemes in RGB color space
7,5,15   ... traditional pm3d (black-blue-red-yellow)
3,11,6   ... green-red-violet
23,28,3  ... ocean (green-blue-white); try also all other permutations
21,22,23 ... hot (black-red-yellow-white)
30,31,32 ... color printable on gray (black-blue-violet-yellow-white)
33,13,10 ... rainbow (blue-green-yellow-red)
34,35,36 ... AFM hot (black-red-yellow-white)
```

Before I will try to figure out some arbitrary combinations I want to ask you, if you have experience of a nice color map that can be printed in color scale and also be readable for black/white prints. For a lot of color scales, the problem occur that in gray scale, we get the  same gray color twice  for two different values (example the traditional rainbow palette).

Just for completeness, the color combination mentioned in the help function can be used but I am searching for another color combination like -> red and green or some answer about how to figure out a good color combination that can be used for color and gray scale plots.

Thanks in advance and I hope the question is understandable, with all informations and not too simple.

Answer (score 0):

The sequential color schemes from the colorbrewer project would work:
https://github.com/aschn/gnuplot-colorbrewer